# Ember js: Getting big amounts of data from a backend

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Here is the problem: the request from the backend takes ~2s, but wrapping the data with ember models takes ~5s. Is there any way **not** to use Ember **models** at all? Pagination has already been implemented.

I've found https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-ajax but I'm not sure if it can help.

Comment: You can use the returned JSON directly, and skip Ember Data completely. With all that entails :P

Comment: Not an easy problem. I suggest you look at http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/best-way-to-handle-loading-thousands-of-records/6087/14.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider to use a Paging!

On the Server and/or on the Client!

Are you sure the wrapping is that costly, not the rendering? Glimmer at the current stage has a poor initial rendering performance. This will improve in future ember versions!

But you can use ember without `ember-data` if you want to!
Just return plain JS Structures in your `model` hooks, or anywhere you want it! So this *will work*:

```
model() {
  return Ember.RSVP.resolve($.getJSON('/myUrl'));
}
```

Comment: At least based on my experience, the key bottleneck is the populating of the data into the store, not the rendering. By the way, I'm not sure `Ember.RSVP.resolve(jQueryPromise)` is going to do what you want. For instance, the jQuery promise has no `catch` method, so errors might not be reported the way you hope.

Comment: `Ember.RSVP.resolve` actually does what you expect! Also `catch` is not part of the `Promises/A+` specification, the signature is `then(onSuccess, onError)`! And this is supported by jQuery thenables. Still the jQuery thenables are broken for chaining, but `Ember.RSVP.resolve` will fix this by wrapping the broken thenable in a RSVP Promise.